# Meaning of potentials in Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential, flow, vector-fields, potential-flow

I am trying to understand the meaning of the potentials $U$ and $A$ arising in the Helmholtz decomposition of a vector field $\vec{V}$:

$\vec{V} = \nabla U + \nabla \times A$

Let's focus on the curl-free potential $U$ and please excuse me for being very informal (I do not have a strong maths background):

$\vec{V} = \nabla U$

What does the potential tell me about the vector field? I know extrema are related to sink and source behavior in the vector field. Are there any circumstances in which the magnitude, i.e. the specific value of $U$, says something about the vector field? For example, are there any conditions under which the potentials tell me "how much" the vector field behaves like a source or sink (vortex) at a given location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the absolute value of $U$ does not tell you anything in general, since $U$ and $U+c$ are equivalent potentials, i.e. they lead to exactly the same vector field $V$, for any constant $c$. This is what one may call a gauge transformation; you may fix the constant by requiring e.g. $U=0$ at  some fixed position.

Note that this all holds for a 3D vector field depending on 3D spatial coordinates. If you are considering some aditional variable, such as time, the constant $c$ can be any function of time, $c(t)$, and while you can, e.g., impose $U(\vec r_0,t)=0$ for some fixed $\vec r_0$ and all $t$, this does not in general provide any obvious intuition (AFAICT).

Next, the source-or-sink character of $\vec V$ is captured by the [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec V$, which you can calculate in terms of the potentials as $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec V=\Delta U$ (note that this holds even for nonzero curl, since the divergence of a curl vanishes). Clearly, this is invariant under gauge transformations.

Thus, to evaluate the "source strength", you would have to evaluate $\Delta U$. On the other hand, you do not need to lok at the potential; you can just compute $\phi:=\vec\nabla \cdot \vec V$ (which is a scalar function) and work with that.

Incidentally, the "vorticity" of $\vec V$ is given by the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)), i.e. $\vec\nabla\times\vec V=\vec\nabla\times\vec\nabla\times A=\vec\nabla \left(\vec\nabla\cdot \vec A\right)-\Delta \vec A$.

(In your linked related question, you mention a discrete setting. I know nothing about that.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand the first part and the second one makes sense too. Is there a way to compare potentials between two states of a vector field (e.g. at two timepoints)? I guess my confusion comes from a discrete setting where the Helmholtz decomposition potentials seem to be superior for identify singularities compared to using the divergence or curl directly. It seems that while the divergence could be compared between two states of a vector field the potentials can't? I have posted a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367368), any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The specific value of U says nothing unless you define it such that it does. A handy thing about physics is that you can set the 0 of your potential energy to whatever is convenient. For instance, in a spring we tend to set it to 0 at the point of equilibrium, meaning the potential is non-negative everywhere. However, with gravity we tend to set it at 0 for a point at infinity, meaning the potential is negative everywhere. All that actually matters is that the sum of kinetic and potential energy of a system remain constant, and the gradient of the potential tells you about how potential energy is traded with kinetic energy and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Assuming that I compute curl-free potentials from two distinct vector fields and I choose their mean to be zero. If one of the local maxima is larger than one of the local maxima of the other vector field, can I make a statement about the larger maximum behaving more like a source than the one in the other vector field? Is there a way to compare the two vector fields based on the values of their potentials?

Comment: The only thing that ever matters with a scalar potential like this is DIFFERENCES. Think of a person in an airplane and the gravitational potential of the earth. Does it affect how much speed they gain approaching the ground if we consider the ground a 0 potential or a point at infinity the 0 potential? No, because the difference between where they are and the ground is the same. I can't think of a situation where the mean potential being 0 would be useful. Also, in the case of the electric potential of an electron, it's sizeless, so the potential is INIFINITE at the electron. Average that!

Comment: What it does tend to affect though is how easy it is to solve a problem, because when you integrate over the potential its handy if at one end of the potential's antiderivative you get 0. That means you can ignore that part of it and focus on the other one.

Comment: OK, I might have actually asked the wrong question initially. What I want to know is (how) can I make the potentials in the Helmholtz decomposition comparable between two different states of the vector field. I guess this boils down to choosing the reference potential of both states such that the differences from that reference are comparable across the states. Eventually, I want to compare a sink in the first state to a sink in the second state of the vector field, such that I can make a statement like “A sink is stronger in the first state compared to a sink in the second state”.

Comment: If you define the potentials using the same reference then you can certainly compare them. The issue is that the value of a potential at a point is useless on its own. Take a gravity well for instance, even if you properly work out the potential including inside the planet, the measurement of the potential at a point gives you information about the mass of the planet, but only if you also know how far you are from the centre of mass. In more complicated potentials the only way to quantify sinks and sources is using divergence/gaussian surfaces.